# Creating two Survival curves from two different datasets on the same plot

Tags: r

I am new to R and am working with two different datasets. I believe I was able to create the Survival curves for each, individually with the code below. But now I would like to create an image where both curves show up on the same graph, so I can compare them to each other. Thank you!

Code:
kmsurvival<-with(ConKRAS, Surv(ConKRAS$SurvivalTime, ConKRAS$Status))

km_fit<-survfit(Surv(ConKRAS$SurvivalTime, ConKRAS$Status)~1, data=ConKRAS)

plot(km_fit)

kmsurvival2<-with(ConKRAS, Surv(DisKRAS$SurvivalTime, DisKRAS$Status))

km_fit2<-survfit(Surv(DisKRAS$SurvivalTime, DisKRAS$Status)~1, data=DisKRAS)

plot(km_fit2)

Comment: Without having a dataset it's hard to answer - but what's different between ConKRAS and DisKRAS?  The best way to get both curves in a graph will be to combine the two datasets so you can color or facet by Con vs. Dis

Comment: Ok, thank you, I decided to try and do that to make it easier